# How evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1+a\times (1+b)^{k-1})^{-k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have trouble to evaluate or approximate the following series: $$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}
\left[1 + a\times\left(1 + b\right)^{k-1}\right]^{-k},\
\mbox{where}\ a > 0\ \mbox{and}\ b \in \left[-.1,.1\right]\
\mbox{are constants.}
$$

Please guide me.

Comment: What are those $a$, $b$, $k$?

Comment: @idriskameni I have edited question. $k$ is summation index.

Comment: Can $b$ be $<-1$?

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 No.

Comment: Since b is very small, an easy approximation would be to set it to 0. In this case you have SUM{(1+a)^-k} for all a > 0. This then becomes a simple geometric series which you can find the formula for with a simple google search.